# How to scrape multiple pages for the same item using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to scrape multiple pages for the same item. But every time I yield, it returns an increment of the list of items instead of all the sub-items in the same item's list.

```
class GdSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pcs'
    start_urls = [...]

    def parse(self, response):
        PC= dict()
        PC['Name'] = response.css('h2::text').get()
        components_urls = response.css('a::attr(href)').get()
        components = []
        for url in components_urls:
            req = yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url), self.parse_component)
            components.append(parse_component(req))
        PC['components'] = components
        yield PC

    def parse_component(self, response):
        component_name = response.css('h1::text')
        component_tag = response.css('div[class="tag"]::text').get()
        yield {"component_name": component_name, "component_tag": component_tag}
```

My out should look like:

```
{"Name": "HP 15", "components": [.....]}
```

But it scrapes everything independently:

```
{"Name": "HP 15", "components":  [<generator object GdSpider.parse_part_component at 0x000001B8A7405230>]

{component1}
{component2}
```

How can I return one item with all the components inside it using @inline-requests decorator for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:** Use `async await`

```py
class GdSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pcs'
    start_urls = [...]

    async def parse(self, response):
        PC = dict()
        PC['Name'] = response.css('h2::text').get()
        components_urls = response.css('a::attr(href)').get()
        components = []
        for url in components_urls:
            req = scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url), self.parse_component)
            res = await self.crawler.engine.download(req, self)
            components.append(self.parse_component(res))
        PC['components'] = components
        yield PC

    def parse_component(self, response):
        component_name = response.css('h1::text')
        component_tag = response.css('div[class="tag"]::text').get()
        return {"component_name": component_name, "component_tag": component_tag}
```

**Options 2:** Use a class member variable.

(Notice that `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` is 1).

```py
class GdSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pcs'
    start_urls = [...]
    components = []

    custom_settings = {'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1}
    
    def parse(self, response):
        PC = dict()
        PC['Name'] = response.css('h2::text').get()
        components_urls = response.css('a::attr(href)').get()

        for url in components_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url), self.parse_component)

        PC['components'] = self.components
        yield PC

    def parse_component(self, response):
        component_name = response.css('h1::text')
        component_tag = response.css('div[class="tag"]::text').get()
        self.components.append({"component_name": component_name, "component_tag": component_tag})
```

Comment: Option one doesn't work, it  it stopped yielding the components separately and yields the item only which is part of the solution `{"Name": "HP 15", 'components': [<generator object GdSpider.parse_component at 0x00000255FD0A0AC0>]`. Option 2 returns empty list. And is inefficient because I have many PCs so the list will add components of previous PCs

Comment: I know option 2 is inefficient but I wanted to include it as it's also a solution. About option 1 if I understand you correctly then you should change the `yield` in `parse_component` method to `return`.